# How can I get ionic-lab view at Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ionic-framework

How I can get ionic-lab view on Heroku? My "app" is running at Heroku but I can't find a way to get de ionic-lab view.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an Ionic project with the `--lab` then you'll get something like `http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab`.

So, with this in mind, say your app is running on heroku and a link is something like `https://ionic-rocks-2016.herokuapp.com/` then just try adding `ionic-lab` to the link, like so: `https://ionic-rocks-2016.herokuapp.com/ionic-lab`.

Comment: And how do you run the app?

Comment: At Heroku I use this script to run Ionic:

`var express = require('express'),
app = express();
app.use(express.static('www'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});`